# How to pass Raw Data in Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In post man we include this in body as raw data 
**grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin**

How do we write the same thing in Ajax ?How do we pass it to the data parameter of Ajax ?

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/",
    type: "POST",
    **data: JSON.stringify([
        {id: 1, name: "Shahed"}, 
        {id: 2, name: "Hossain"}
    ]),**--------> how do we pass above grant type here ?
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType   : "json",
    success    : function(){
        console.log("Pure jQuery Pure JS object");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code,

```
$.ajax({
   method     : "POST",
   url        : "/",
   dataType   : "json",
   data       : { grant_type: "password", username: "admin",password:"admin" }
 })
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
 });
```